# How to optimize code using MiePython so that fit is better

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am trying to determine the effects of mie scattering on my data. My theoretical fit looks awful. I'd appreciate any insights here on how to optimize this code. I can send the data over if needed:

```
# Constants and known parameters
incidence_angle = 2.5  # in degrees
refractive_index = 1.31

# Define the Mie scattering model function
def mie_scattering(wavelength, particle_radius):
# Convert particle radius from nanometers to meters
particle_radius_m = particle_radius * 1e-9

# Calculate the size parameter
x = 2 * np.pi * particle_radius_m / wavelength

# Calculate the cosine of the scattering angle
mu = np.cos(np.deg2rad(incidence_angle))

# Perform Mie scattering calculation
S1, S2 = miepython.mie_S1_S2(x, refractive_index, mu)

# Calculate the expected reflectance based on the scattering properties
qsca = 4 * np.pi * np.sum((2 * n + 1) * (np.abs(S1)**2 + np.abs(S2)**2) for n in 
range(x.size)) / np.sum(x**2)
expected_reflectance = qsca / (np.pi * particle_radius_m**2)

return expected_reflectance

# Define the vectorized version of the Mie scattering model function
vec_mie_scattering = np.vectorize(mie_scattering)

# Define the objective function for curve fitting
def objective_function(wavelength, particle_radius):
expected_reflectance = vec_mie_scattering(wavelength, particle_radius)
return expected_reflectance

# Perform curve fitting to find the particle radius
initial_guess = [0.5]  # Initial guess for the particle radius (in nm)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(objective_function, x_data, y_data, p0=initial_guess)

# Retrieve the optimized particle radius
optimal_radius = popt[0]
print("Optimized Particle Radius: ", optimal_radius, " nm")

# Generate the fitted curve using the optimized particle radius
fitted_curve = vec_mie_scattering(x_data, optimal_radius)

# Plot the experimental data and fitted curve
plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'b-', label='Experimental Data')
plt.plot(x_data, fitted_curve, 'r-', label='Fitted Curve')
plt.xlabel('Wavelength (nm)')
plt.ylabel('Reflectance')
plt.title('Mie Scattering Fit')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

The theoretical fit gives me an optimized particle radius of 13669735570.583977  nm, and my particles are more like 20 nm.

Comment: Please update your question with properly formatted code.